# Can i split a .txt by an emptyLine using the scanner method?

Tags: java, arrays

hej!

I have been following the new mooc.fi since it has got out.

I'm blocked with this problem : 
I have a document.txt with different recipes on it following this rule: All the information is on a new line, the first information the name, the seconds the cooking time, and the following are the ingredients. A blank line shows that there the recipe is over and we pass to another one.
I have to use a scanner method scanner.hasNextLine.

I succeeded to create an ArrayList, by adding each line of the document with .split("\n") but I have no knowledge, or not the logic to do have only the Name of the recipe or the cooking time for example(An also have to work thinking that is someone add an ingredient, the code is still working, so I can't really use a .get(0)

Here is a link to the seventh exercises call recipe search.

https://java-programming.mooc.fi/part-7/3-larger-exercises

I don't need a full answer for the exercise, I just need a little clue.